# Copy the files automatically to destination as soon as created

Tags: shell-script, file-copy

Is there any way to copy the file in Unix  as soon as it is created?
I have one location where files will be created in different timings.How can I copy the files automatically using shell script to some other location in Unix?

Comment: Perhapse XY http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 5):

```
inotifywait -e close_write --format "%f" --monitor . |
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    #cp "$line" destination/ #this would not replicate directories
    tar cf - "$line" | tar -C destination/ xf - #this should replicate directories
  done
```

should do the trick, unless the number of files in your directory (I'm using `.` for the current directory) exceeds your system's limit for inotify watches (fs.inotify.max_user_watches, as coteyr mentions).

Comment: Also important to be aware of the file watch limit (fs.inotify.max_user_watches) I hit that limit all the time using inotify.

Comment: Thank you guys very much for the comments. I've incorporated both into the answer. I believe `--monitor` switch along with `close_write` should make it reliable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.But, I do not have rsync installed on my linux machine.Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Install it if you can. `rsync` is useful. But I believe there is. Give me a few seconds.

Comment: Do you have tar or cpio?

Comment: I tried to install rsync in my system.But, I couldn't do that.

Comment: if tar means compress feature, then I have tar. I am not sure what is cpio

Comment: I've edited the answer. Tar creates archives. Archives are sort of concatenated directory trees that can be extracted into directory trees elsewhere. Compression is an option. Here I'm sending an uncompressed directory tree via a pipe to the destination directory, the purpose of which is to recreate directories (if the newly created file is not directly in '.' but rather inside a directory or multiple directories).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24585/discussion-between-m-nehru-and-pskocik).

Comment: Note that the limit is on the number of watches. Here you have only one (on the current directory). It assumes file names don't contain newline characters. To WA that, you can use `--format=%f/` and look for that trailing /

Answer (score 0):

You can't really copy files the instant they are created with a shell script alone. Three solutions that come to mind.

1. rsync with cron - It's simple, standard, and easy. Once every so often ( one time an hour) you run rsync against the directory. Huge structures can be synced in seconds, depending on the amount of changes.
2. [Gluster](http://www.gluster.org/download/) or similar. Depending on needs.
3. Just use a symlink.

Comment: What is symlink? how can I use it to copy the files automatically?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html

Comment: You should google it. It's complex to explain but easy to grasp.