# Monitor folders mounted via SSHFS

Tags: filesystems, mount, sshfs

I want to monitor changes made a folder that is mounted via `SSHFS`.

I have tried `iwatch` but it does not notify when a new file is created, below is the syntax I am using with `iwatch`:

`iwatch -e create /mnt/mme01/`

Any idea why this is not working and how it can be achieved?

Comment: This may solve your problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208206/copy-the-files-automatically-to-destination-as-soon-as-created/208214

Answer (score 7):

SSHFS doesn't implement the inotify API. Making that work would require a fundamental redesign for two reasons:

- SSHFS uses [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) to communicate with the server. The SFTP protocol has no facility to be notified of file changes on the server side. The server might not even have a file change notification mechanism — this could be made an optional feature of the protocol, but SFTP simply doesn't include this.
- SSHFS is built on [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), and FUSE doesn't provide an interface to inotify, so FUSE filesystems will never generate any inotify events.

You'll have to set up your watch on the server side.

```
ssh server.example.com inotifywait -m -e create /path/to/mme01 | …
```

Comment: Many thanks Gilles! I will check out your recommendation!