# Transfer a file between different users: best strategy?

Tags: linux, sudo, root, group, acl

I have a program that is doing some stuff. It is running under user A.

A very little part of it is to transfer a file to a directory in the home of user B.
The transfer is done by a API-call of the language it is written and not by a system-call of a shell-command.

Now I see multiple ways to do that transfer.

- Run the program as root.
- Put A and B into the same group and adjust the directory-ownership
- sudo the program
- make the move with a system-call and sudo that
- put the file locally in A and make the transfer externally (outsource the problem)
- ACL the directory of B
- ...

I think the requirement is common since running a program via root is bad taste. What would be the most common way to handle it?

**EDIT**

Program of A generates the file. B should be able to read and delete it.

Comment: I would go with the ACL option.

Comment: Is the issue that the file, from user B's perspective, is not readable or located in an inaccessible directory? This is not actually spelled out in the question. If that was _not_ the case, no special handling of permissions would be necessary, obviously, as long as you copy the data rather than just rename/move the file (to get the correct ownership on B's end).

Comment: Added the requirement. A creates the file, B reads and deletes it.

Comment: If you are already messing up with permissions and root's stuff, then you may consider using `bindfs` with proper user option to i.e create new files as another user

Comment: I will check bindfs, thanks. Is there a way where I do not need to mess up with permissions and root stuff?

Answer (score 1):

If it's important to not see the other files of A user, then make a separate common directory where both users have read write rights and put the files there.

Or you can copy/move the file as soon as it is created with inotifywatch and chown to B, here is an example, put it in cron

[Copy the files automatically to destination as soon as created](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208206/copy-the-files-automatically-to-destination-as-soon-as-created)